# VB .NET: How to get reference to a row in a 2D-array

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays, reference, dimensional

I have a function that returns a 1D-array like this:

`Public Function KeyConvert([args]) As Byte()`

and a 2 dimension array:

```
Public KeyList(15, 5) As Byte
```

Which can be seen as 15 rows,each row is a 5 element array, as we all already knew.

Now I want to call the function and assign the result (which is a 1D array) to a row (say row 4) in the KeyList array. At first I thought the code should be like

```
Keylist(4) = KeyConvert([args])
```

But that didn't work. I cannot find a way to reference to that specific row.

So anybody have any idea? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You want a [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkhhsz9t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), not a m-d one.

Something closer to:

```
Public KeyList(15)() As Byte
```

Comment: Thank you everyone. I think I got confused between the two definitions: 2 dimensional array and an array of arrays. This should solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

There is no notion in VB.Net (or C#) of "a row" (or "a column") in a 2-dimensional array.  Array elements in .Net can only be accessed one at a time.

If you make your KeyList variable be a one-dimensional array of 5-element arrays, then you will be able to use the syntax you showed.

If you need to keep KeyList as a 2-dimensional array so that you can more easily access any single "point" within it, then you can write a method that is passed the row to update and the 5-element array whose elements are to be copied, and have that method copy the 5 values one at a time into the respective columns.